# Multiple Optional Parameters with Angular JS ( UI-Router)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url, angular-ui-router

I have a page which displays products from a JSON REST web service. Not sure if this is the best way, but I am trying to use query parameters on the page to be able to filter based on MinPrice and MaxPrice (other filters would be added later as well) - however, i can't get multiple parameters working.

for example:

MinPrice and MaxPrice are both optional.

When I click MinPrice 30, i get the following URL, which is fine:

> **#/minPriceParam=3**

If i then click MaxPrice  60, I would expect

> **#/minPriceParam=30&maxPriceParam=60**

however what i actually get is

> **#/maxPriceParam=60**
>   i.e. it's lost the minPriceParam=30 part.

this is the simplified code that i have

```
<a ui-sref="minPrice({ minPriceParam:30 })">   MinPrice 30</a>
<a ui-sref="maxPrice({ maxPriceParam:60 })">   MaxPrice 60</a>
```

JS File

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider

      .state('minPrice', {
        url: '/?minPriceParam&maxPriceParam'

        , controller: function ($scope, $StateParams) 
         {$scope.minimumPrice = $StateParams.min;}
    })

        .state('maxPrice', {
        url: '/?minPriceParam&maxPriceParam'

        , controller: function ($scope, $StateParams) { $scope.maximumPrice = $StateParams.max; }
    })



});
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this](http://benfoster.io/blog/ui-router-optional-parameters) example, I think you can just put your default parameters in a `params` section:

```
<a ui-sref="eitherPrice()">   MinPrice 30</a>
<a ui-sref="eitherPrice()">   MaxPrice 60</a>

app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $stateProvider
        .state('eitherPrice', {
            params {
                minPriceParam:30,
                maxPriceParam:60
            }            
            , url: '/?minPriceParam&maxPriceParam'

            , controller: function ($scope, $StateParams) {
              $scope.minimumPrice = $StateParams.minPriceParam;
              $scope.maximumPrice = $StateParams.maxPriceParam;
             }
        })

});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work either.. your link was the example that i originally followed not sure why its not working though.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your code:
Firstly your state parameters names are `minPriceParam` and `maxPriceParam` respectively. You cannot access them with name `min` and `max`.
Further you have to send both the `minPriceParam` and `maxPriceParam` when you are calling the maxPrice state. Please refer to the following code.

```
app.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

$stateProvider
  .state('minPrice', {
    url: '/?minPriceParam&maxPriceParam'
    , controller: function ($scope, $stateParams) 
     {$scope.minimumPrice = $stateParams.minPriceParam;}
})
    .state('maxPrice', {
    url: '/?minPriceParam&maxPriceParam', 
    controller: function ($scope, $stateParams)
    { $scope.minimumPrice = $stateParams.minPriceParam;
      $scope.maximumPrice = $stateParams.maxPriceParam; }
})
});
```

In your html, you have to send the minimum price as a stateparameter when you are calling the maxPrice state.

```
<a ui-sref="minPrice({ minPriceParam:30 })">   MinPrice 30</a>
<a ui-sref="maxPrice({ minPriceParam:minimumPrice,maxPriceParam:60 })"> MaxPrice 60</a>
```

Comment: Hi - no that didn't seem to work.. I'm not sure that $scope.minimumPrice is getting to the controller because when I add {{ minimumPrice }} it shows nothing..

Comment: Do i need to explicitly state the controller name somewhere in the state section?

Comment: Yes do need to do that, Do you create different templates for minPrice and maxPrice states?

Comment: Templates would be the same, added the Controller into .state but query parameters still not getting picked up in the controller